# SQL query not working with multiple condition

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I'm trying to get filtered posts,
but query isn't working with multiple conditions

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.ID as ID, 
    p.post_title as post_title
FROM wp_posts p
    INNER JOIN wp_ulisting_listing_attribute_relationships ular ON ular.listing_id = p.ID
WHERE 
    p.post_type='listing' 
    AND p.post_status='publish'
    AND ular.attribute='square_feet' AND ular.value BETWEEN 11011 AND 11023
    AND ular.attribute='price' AND ular.value BETWEEN 6500000 AND 100888000
```

if I remove `AND ular.attribute='square_feet' AND ular.value BETWEEN 11011 AND 11023`

or
`AND ular.attribute='square_feet' AND ular.value BETWEEN 11011 AND 11023`

it works.

The same thing with this query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
        p.ID as ID, 
        p.post_title as post_title
    FROM wp_posts p 
        INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON tr.object_id = p.ID
        INNER JOIN wp_ulisting_listing_type_relationships ultr ON ultr.listing_id = p.ID
        INNER JOIN wp_ulisting_listing_attribute_relationships ular ON ular.listing_id = p.ID
    WHERE 
        p.post_type='listing' 
        AND p.post_status='publish'
        AND ular.attribute='beds' AND ular.value=274
        AND tr.term_taxonomy_id in (251)
        AND ular.attribute='status'AND ular.value=130
        AND ular.attribute='stories' AND ular.value=267
        AND ultr.listing_type_id=7125
```

Works only if I leave only one `ular.` condition, but all demo data is from one post.

**Note:** I have post with this attributes.

Thanks

Comment: Edited to clarify that the `DISTINCT` keyword belongs to `SELECT DISTINCT` .

Comment: is it not filtering? or is it giving an error message? you're missing alot of info

Comment: Not filtering without any errors.

Comment: Use `or` for the last condition `ular.attribute='price' AND ular.value BETWEEN 6500000 AND 100888000`

Comment: @forpas result of query is null, but why? if I have post with this data, and this request satisfies with this data, it should find 1 post.
If I leave only 1 condition with ular. - it works

so I guess I've some error in AND conditions, maybe I should add some brackets...

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is there any single row that matches `ular.attribute='square_feet'` **and** `ular.attribute='price'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want *all* attributes to match for the post.  For this, use aggregation.  What you really want to accomplish is rather unclear, but something like this:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title
FROM wp_posts p JOIN
     wp_term_relationships tr
     ON tr.object_id = p.ID JOIN
     wp_ulisting_listing_type_relationships ultr
     ON ultr.listing_id = p.ID JOIN
     wp_ulisting_listing_attribute_relationships ular ON ular.listing_id = p.ID
WHERE p.post_type = 'listing' AND
      p.post_status = 'publish' AND
      tr.term_taxonomy_id in (251) AND
      ultr.listing_type_id = 7125
GROUP BY p.ID, p.post_title
HAVING SUM(ular.attribute = 'beds' AND ular.value = 274) > 0 AND
       SUM(ular.attribute = 'status' AND ular.value = 130) > 0 AND
       SUM(ular.attribute = 'stories' AND ular.value = 267);
```

Answer (score 1):

This condition:

```
ular.attribute='square_feet' AND ular.value BETWEEN 11011 AND 11023
```

and this:

```
ular.attribute='price' AND ular.value BETWEEN 6500000 AND 100888000
```

can't be true for the same row.

Maybe you want:

```
AND (
  (ular.attribute='square_feet' AND ular.value BETWEEN 11011 AND 11023)
  OR
  (ular.attribute='price' AND ular.value BETWEEN 6500000 AND 100888000)
)
```

For the same reason, in your 2nd query these conditions are mutually exclusive:

```
ular.attribute='beds' AND ular.value=274
ular.attribute='status'AND ular.value=130
ular.attribute='stories' AND ular.value=267
```

Change them to:

```
AND (
  (ular.attribute='beds' AND ular.value=274) 
  OR 
  (ular.attribute='status'AND ular.value=130) 
  OR 
  (ular.attribute='stories' AND ular.value=267)
)
```

Or:

```
AND (ular.attribute, ular.value) IN (('beds', 274), ('status', 130), ('stories', 267))
```

Answer (score 1):

With below conditions, you are essentially trying to "**find a row having attribute value equal to both 'Square_feet' and 'Price'**". Its not possible right? One row can have one value in a column.

You got to use OR (shown below) which translate to "**Find a row whose value is either Square_feet or Price**".

**For First query**

```
-----Your conditions------

ular.attribute='square_feet' AND ular.value BETWEEN 11011 AND 11023
AND ular.attribute='price' AND ular.value BETWEEN 6500000 AND 100888000

----------Correct way of writing it--------

AND ((ular.attribute='square_feet' AND ular.value BETWEEN 11011 AND 11023)
OR (ular.attribute='price' AND ular.value BETWEEN 6500000 AND 100888000))
```

**For second query conditions**

```
-----Your conditions------

ular.attribute='status'AND ular.value=130
And ular.attribute='stories' AND ular.value=267

----------Correct way of writing it--------

AND ((ular.attribute='status'AND ular.value=130)
 OR (ular.attribute='stories' AND ular.value=267))
```